# Linear algebra - Money issue

Tags: linear-algebra

"Salma has 70 dollars more than Thea. She receives 50 dollars from Thea and now has twice as much dollars as Thea has. How many dollars does Salma have now?

Thoughts:

$S = T + 70$

$T = S-70$

$T =  2T-120$

$T = 120$

$2*120 = 240$

But the right answer should be 340, how comes? Explanations of what I did wrong and should've done is appreciated.

Comment: Why does $T=2T -120$?

Comment: Edit: I made a mistake, it must be $$ T-50 = 2T + 120 $$, but I don't know how to solve this problem though?

Comment: If Salma has twice as many dollars *after* receiving 50 from Thea then $S+50 = 2(T-50).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}&\mbox{Before}&\mbox{After}\\ \hline 
\mbox{Thea}&T&T-50 \\ \hline
\mbox{Salma}&T+70&T+120\\ \hline
\end{array} $$

So $T+120=2(T-50)$.

You can solve this to find Thea's starting amount, and then determine all the other amounts.

Comment: $T = 220$ ... $220+120 = 340$. I must say that you really helped me to solve this hard assignment in a basic way, really, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

So I had trouble understanding what you wrote, so I went ahead and wrote it down myself.

S = T + 70 + 50 (the original S was T + 70, now we add 50 from what we got from T)

S = 2(T-50) (S is equal to 2 times the original T subtracted 50, because T lost $50)

Now we have 2 equations:

1) S= T + 120

2) S = 2T - 100

multiply the first equation by -2 to cancel out the T's and then add the two equations together.

-2s = -2T - 240

+s =  2T - 100

-s = 0 - 340

s = 340.